# Vagrant - npm install doesn't work

Tags: ubuntu, npm, vagrant, npm-install, node-modules

Have a trouble to run `npm install` in Vagrant. Get this message. I have installed modules in root dir (Before I started `vagrant ssh`) But I need it to install after `vagrant ssh`

```
Last login: Sun Jun 11 09:25:02 2017 from 10.0.2.2
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ npm install
The program 'npm' is currently not installed. To run 'npm' please ask your administrator to install the package 'npm'
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ cd /vagrant
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/vagrant$ npm install
The program 'npm' is currently not installed. To run 'npm' please ask your administrator to install the package 'npm'
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/vagrant$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to install `node` and `npm`

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install nodejs npm
```

Comment: In the `cd /vagrant` or root dir ?

Comment: @DenisLapiLapadatovic anywhere